# What is the purpose of having hashCode in Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, hashcode, api-design

Can someone please explain the purpose why do java people override the `hascode` in `Optional`

Comment: What do you mean by "java people override the `hashCode` in `Optional`"? Normally there's no reason to do that (it's already implemented in a useful way).

Comment: For the same reason as the `hashCode`  in `String` and other value-classes :)

Comment: Overriding `hashCode` in `Optional` enables sensible use of `HashSet/Map` with `Optional` entries respectively keys. Without the override, it would be the system hash of the `Optional` object. The override uses the hash of the underlying object.

And above all: `equals` and `hashCode` have to be consistent!

    equals(a,b) == true => hashCode(a) == hashCode(b)

Ergo: If you override `equals` (is done in `Optional` to make two instances having equals underlying objects the same), you also have to override `hashCode` in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allows you to store `Optional`s (whose value types also override `equals` and `hashCode`) in `HashSet`s and use them as keys in `HashMap`s.

If `Optional` didn't override `equals` and `hashCode`, the following code would output `2` instead of `1`:

```
Map<Optional<String>,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(Optional.of("someKey"),"someValue");
map.put(Optional.of("someKey"),"someOtherValue"); 
System.out.println(map.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

From JavaDoc:

> Returns the hash code value of the present value, if any, or 0 (zero) if no value is present.

So you can check if objects inside Optional is equals to each others. It also correspond well with implementation of `equals` method.